# Fetching entire branch of MIB

Tags: snmp, mib

I'm still quite new to SNMP and I was wondering how I would go about getting an entire branch of a MIB with as few queries as possible.

My approach:
Use GETBULK messages to get `pow(2,tries)` entries at a time and then stop when I get an object that don't match as a child of the object specified by my OID

Why do I need it:
I'm trying to get a variant sized branch of the MIB, the ipRouteTable part to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know SNMP has a WALK operation where you can visit all objects in turn? Net-SNMP has such a utility,

http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/man/snmpwalk.html

Comment: Sadly GETNEXT messages will guarantee worst possible number of queries all the time. snmpbulkwalk is even superior to it, though im skeptical to both.

Note: I'm working in a WMN test environment with AODV so any chattiness is undesirable.